# How to make the rows within a facet appear according to the level of another vector?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

The goal is to get the "name"s with increasing "startTime"s  displayed from top to bottom, within each facet.  Facet A is wrong; Facet B is correct.

```
library(tidyverse)
my_tribble <- tribble(
  ~name, ~order.x,  ~startTime, ~endTime, ~order.y, ~endTime.y, ~diff, ~area,
  "unit1", "dump", 0, 1, "wait", 2, 2, "A",
  "unit3", "dump", 5, 7, "wait", 9, 4, "A",
  "unit4", "dump", 8, 9, "wait", 10, 2, "B",
  "unit2", "dump", 17, 20, "wait", 23, 6, "B"
)

ggplot(my_tribble) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = startTime, ymax = endTime.y, x = name),position = position_dodge(width = 0.2), size = 2) +
  facet_grid(area ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_x_reordered() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Just about every question on SO that includes `ggplot2` and *"order of <something>"* is resolved with the use of `factor`s, and controlling the `levels` within them.

Comment: I see your solution. Thanks.  I saw many examples similar to yours, but none used the order() function in the same way.  Also, I think I misinterpreted the meaning of "levels" parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
my_tribble$name <- factor(my_tribble$name, levels = my_tribble$name[order(-my_tribble$startTime)])
ggplot(my_tribble) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = startTime, ymax = endTime.y, x = name),position = position_dodge(width = 0.2), size = 2) +
  facet_grid(area ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image: ggplot2, reordered factors]

Comment: Your use of "-my_tribble$startTime" makes a big difference.  Why the need for "-" ? Seems like I should be able to leave the smallest startTime as the lowest value... instead of reversing the order.

Comment: The y-axis has the lowest (ordered-first) values on the bottom. Since you want the lowest values to track down from the top, we need to reverse the order. One way is to use R's `rev` function; another way it to order the negative of the values.